# Jenkins pipeline shared library - passing arguments

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build a function that accepts parameters to override defaults but I keep getting "null".

I have written a simple function:

```
// vars/Run.groovy
def test(String type, String parallel = 'yes') {
    println(type)
    println(parallel)
}
```

My pipeline looks like this:

```
node('master') {
    Run.test('unit')
    Run.test('unit', parallel = 'no')
}
```

The result I get is:

```
unit
yes

unit
null
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to pass the value. This will override your default value.

```
Run.test('unit', 'no')
```

Comment: But what do you do if you have several optional args?
example:
def test(String type, String foo = 'bar', String parallel = 'yes')

and I only want to override 'parallel' ?

Comment: I have posted an answer with optional and mandatory arguements in a full example. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54181094/3002336

Comment: That full example doesn't help. It's too complex, no explanation, and it doesn't answer the question.